# Flutter App Failed To Run after latest Update

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**Environment Details**
Windows + VS Code
Flutter 1.17.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8af6b2f038 (3 days ago) • 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
Engine • revision ee76268252
Tools • Dart 2.8.4

**Error From Debug Console**

```
E:\apps\flutterCode\android\app\src\main\java\com\example\testApp\MainActivity.java:3: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
                                 ^
E:\apps\flutterCode\android\app\src\main\java\com\example\TestApp\MainActivity.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
                                      ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class MainActivity
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: I found a workaround, create a new flutter project, copy android folder then replace the android folder in the old project.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the minimum SDK version in the `Android/build.gradle` from 16 to 21.
if it is still not working try to change the `build type` function as below.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
```